# How can i retain data without saving the data on a bottom navigation tab change in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am using a bottom navigation bar and input some data like name and a list etc.
So, when i input any data and change the tab then i want that when i come back again to the previous tab the data should retain.

I am expecting a solution for this problem on data retaintion in bottom navigation bar in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code using IndexedStack:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _currentIndex,
          children: const [
            Page1(),
            Page2(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _currentIndex = index),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.first_page), label: 'Page 1'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.last_page), label: 'Page 2'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure that the list of children widgets within the `IndexedStack` is constant. This will prevent widgets from being recreated when `setState()` is applied.